# Native query taking longer time than linked server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-administration

I have the same query running from remote server using linked server and without linked server on native server. Surprisingly its taking 13 seconds in native host server SSMS and from remote server using linked server its taking less than a second!

For example: There are two servers Server A and Server B. On server A there is a linked server with admin account to access data from Server B. I am running a select statement with multiple joins and where conditions. First time it takes aroung 6/7 seconds and second time onward it takes 0 second.

But the same query when fired in SSMS on Server B itself it always takes 13/14 seconds.

All the tables used in the select statement are from Server B.

Is there any reason for that? Host is 2008 standard and remote server is 2008 r2 standard.

Please help me out here.

Comment: I think you are confusing your question marks with exclamation marks there

Comment: Please provide more details on the data load, indexes, physical memory availability and related stuff on both the environments...

Comment: I have updated the question. Please give me some hints.

Comment: Examine the query plans.  Are the search results the same?

Comment: Yes search results are same. In the query from remote server I cannot see anything from the execution plan as it just mention 'remote query'.

Comment: when you access server B directly and execute the query you use the very same credentials you get mapped to by the linked server configuration? what happens if you clear cache & co and reverse the execution order (B first and linked next)?

Comment: Yes the credentials are same ie same user is in both cases. I have cleared everything and now it took 63 sec on Host (server B) and 2 second with linked server! (server A).

Comment: Does not make sense to me.  I can see a query plan a linked server.  Post more details.